# Где после установки найти slim framework на ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: php, android

Где после установки найти slim framework на ubuntu 17.04 ?

Comment: `/usr/local/Slim/Slim.php`?

Comment: нету там Я использовал sudo apt-get install slim

Comment: `/var/www/slim/`?

Comment: Тоже нету в той директории